# avoid repetitive occurence of the same exponent in y axis log scale plot

Tags: python, matplotlib

The following code produces the figure

[image]

Where 10^1 occurs too many times which is not necessary,
How to keep only one occurrence of 10^1 ?

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from matplotlib.ticker import FuncFormatter

# Generate some data
x = np.linspace(start=11, stop=19, num=20)
y = x

# Create figure and axis
fig, ax = plt.subplots()

# Plot data with log scale
ax.plot(x, y)
ax.set_yscale('log')

# Define custom tick formatter for y-axis
def format_y_tick(value, pos):
    if pos == 0:
        return f'{value:.0e}'
    exponent = int(np.log10(value))
    base = value / 10**exponent
    if pos == 1 or exponent != format_y_tick.prev_exponent:
        format_y_tick.prev_exponent = exponent
        return f'{base:.0f}e{exponent}'
    else:
        return f'{base:.0f}'

format_y_tick.prev_exponent = None

ax.yaxis.set_major_formatter(FuncFormatter(format_y_tick))

# Show plot
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 0):

Your function is correct, you need to call it with `ax.yaxis.set_minor_formatter`:

```
from matplotlib.ticker import FuncFormatter, NullLocator

def format_y_tick(value, pos):
    if pos == 0:
        return f'{value:.0e}'
    exponent = int(np.log10(value))
    base = value / 10**exponent
    if pos == 1 or exponent != format_y_tick.prev_exponent:
        format_y_tick.prev_exponent = exponent
        return f'{base:.1f}e{exponent}'
    else:
        return f'{base:.1f}'

format_y_tick.prev_exponent = None

ax.yaxis.set_minor_formatter(FuncFormatter(format_y_tick))
ax.yaxis.set_major_locator(NullLocator())
```

Output:

[image]

With more ticks:

[image]

Comment: thanks, it works! But is there a way to put e1 on top of the tick instead the first occurence?